# How to get tweets from a multiple of friends?

Tags: twitter, linq-to-twitter

this is the my first question in SO witch I use alot btw :). this is the problem/challenge:

I'm building a service where the user can select a number of his facebook and twitter friends, he will then get a combined list of tweets and statuses of those. Facebook was no problem using batch request was very useful and easy to implement. Im trying to get the same result from twitter, but this seems harder then it seem.

I have a list of all my friends (name and user_id), I want to select a few of those friends and retrieve their tweets. Im using linqToTwitter, a direct HTTP request is also welcome :).

this is what im trying:

```
var tweetsResult =
                (from search in twitterCtx.Search
                  where search.Type == SearchType.Search &&
                    search.Query == "from:cinek24 OR from:blaba"
                  select search).Single();
```

this works with public users like cnn but not private friends, and yes i have valid tokens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how you would do the users look-up in LINQ to Twitter:

```
        var users =
            (from user in twitterCtx.User
             where user.Type == UserType.Lookup &&
                   user.ScreenName == "cinek24,blaba"
             select user)
            .ToList();

        users.ForEach(user => Console.WriteLine("Name: " + user.Name));
```

More info here:

http://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Querying%20User%20Details&referringTitle=Getting%20User%20Information

Once you have the users, then you'll have to query each of them for their tweets because the user lookup will only return their last tweet, like this:

```
        var statusTweets =
            from tweet in twitterCtx.Status
            where tweet.Type == StatusType.User
                  && tweet.ScreenName == "cinek24"
                  && tweet.Count == 40
            select tweet;

        tweets.ToList().ForEach(
            tweet => Console.WriteLine(
                "Name: {0}, Tweet: {1}\n",
                tweet.User.Name, tweet.Text));
```

More info on that query here:

http://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Querying%20the%20User%20Timeline&referringTitle=Making%20Status%20Queries%20and%20Calls

Joe

Comment: Thanx for the answer, i guess there is no way that this could be done in one request like facebook. Lets hop Twitter will provide this in the future.

Comment: I already implemented a method witch retreives a N number of tweets of a user, now i loop through that method using different userIds. this takes about 800ms per request witch is a lot of time. I set your answer as accepted because i think there is no way doing it in one request.

Comment: MQoder, that sounds like a Status User query: 
            var statusTweets =
                from tweet in twitterCtx.Status
                where tweet.Type == StatusType.User
                      && tweet.ScreenName == "JoeMayo"
                      && tweet.Count == 200
                select tweet;

Answer (score 2):

This is the API call you need - [users/lookup](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/users/lookup)

```
https://api.twitter.com/1/users/lookup.json?screen_name=twitterapi,twitter,edent,MQoder&include_entities=true
```

This will return the most recent tweet from all those screen_names.  You can also use user_ids if you prefer.

Comment: Thanx for the fast reaction, this is a great way if you were interested in the last tweet, I need to get between 20 and 40 tweets.

Comment: The only way I know to do that is by putting them in a list.